# Extra field when serializing object with Jackson in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-data, jackson-databind

I am using the Jackson JSON library to serialize an object, but the JSON string produced by the ObjectMapper has an extra field that is a duplicate of another field of the class with a different name. I can't figure out where this extra field is coming from and it messes up de-serialization on the other end.

Object Properties

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private int requirement_id;
@JsonProperty("student_uid")
private String student;
private String status;
@Nullable
@JsonProperty("doc_guid")
private String doc_guid;
@Nullable
@JsonProperty("retake_date")
private Date retake_date;
```

Serialization Code

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/student/requirements/{uid}")
public String getStudentRequirements(@PathVariable String uid) throws JsonProcessingException
{
    List<RequirementInstance> requirements = instance_repo.findByStudent(uid);

    if(requirements != null)
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(requirements.toArray());
    }

    return "{\"error\": \"Unable to locate user with UID of " + uid + ".\"}";
}
```

Returned JSON String

> [{
> "id": 1,
> "status": "Incomplete",
> "studentUID": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "docGUID": null,
> "requirementID": 1,
> "retakeDate": null,
> "student_uid": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "doc_guid": null,
> "retake_date": null
> }, {
> "id": 2,
> "status": "Incomplete",
> "studentUID": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "docGUID": null,
> "requirementID": 2,
> "retakeDate": null,
> "student_uid": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "doc_guid": null,
> "retake_date": null
> }, {
> "id": 3,
> "status": "Incomplete",
> "studentUID": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "docGUID": null,
> "requirementID": 3,
> "retakeDate": null,
> "student_uid": "6e8d6c69af58e73c7248364aa59b0c257f6ba1d19782eb9e38890a61ada948ef",
> "doc_guid": null,
> "retake_date": null
> }]

Comment: You need to add more context here. What is the extra field? What is the copy? What is the different name?

Comment: Please add code here instead of posing links to pictures

Comment: Reformatted and tried to add some more context. The JSON string that returned has duplicate values where I set the JSON preoperty with the @JsonProperty annotation. Once in the camel case format, and once with an underscore i.e. (studentUID & student_uid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results from incompatible field/getter/setter naming -- fields would imply properties
Ref : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1609
Verify your getter setters are not mapped property / automatically. Because of this you are seeing duplicate. Refer to teh above link, how to solve it.

Or use property naming strategy in ObjectMapper. Ref : https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jackson-property-naming-strategy/